# Removing "X-Frame-Options" header for a specific controller only

Tags: iframe, asp.net-mvc-5, x-frame-options

I am trying to remove the "X-Frame-Options" header for only a specific controller's actions using:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to work at all.  The only way I can get it to work at all on my site is to add this code to the global.asax below.  I am pretty sure I am missing the correct step in the ASP.NET MVC / IIS pipeline that allows me to overwrite the IIS setting of that header.  Is this possible?

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
}
```

As for why I want to do this, I am building a widget that user's will be able to use on their personal sites through the use of an iframe, but allow them to post back information to our site.  I realize there are security implications to turning this header off, and while I welcome any suggestions on how to mitigate those risks, I just want to know if what I am asking is possible.

Answer (score 5):

**OnResultExecuting** happens too early in the MVC lifecycle. The header has not been set yet.

What you need is the **OnResultExecuted** method which is run after the View is rendered.

Here's how you write a filter class for what you are looking for:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test.Filters
{
    public class RemoveXFrameOptionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, decorate whatever Controller or Action you want this filter applied.

```cs
[RemoveXFrameOptions]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

or

```cs
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [RemoveXFrameOptions]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but not seems to be working. Also, did a Quick Watch on `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers` before removing but only 2 headers present `Server` and `X-AspNetMvc-Version`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried it together with sitecore and it worked like a charme!